# How to calculate Maximum Adjusted Rand Index for cluster number bigger than ground truth cluster number

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I am using the Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) for assessing clustering solutions against ground truth. I am consistently getting higher ARI results with higher cluster numbers (k=5) than the number of clusters in ground truth (k=3).

Since I do not have the same number of clusters, the Adjusted Rand Index will never be equal to 1 (complete agreement with ground truth), as there are more label types in the clustering solution than in ground truth. My question is, is it possible to calculate the maximum possible ARI in this context? And if so, how can I do such a calculation?

Comment: `calculate the maximum possible ARI in this context` It is impossible unless the group corrrespondence between the two being compared partitions is established first. In other words, you must know the groups with _what labels are those surplus groups_ in the cluster partition that do not exist (have the corresponding group) in the reference (ground truth) partition. If you get to know the one-to-one correspondence, the calculation you want becomes, in principle, feasible.

Comment: (cont.) But then, on the other hand, you probably would not need adj Rand or other external clustering criteria anymore - because then you'll find yourself in a classification comparison problem, rather than a clustering comparison problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I suspect there are more subdivisions than the original ground truth shows, and was wondering if there is a mathematical way to answer what the maximum agreement between a list of 3 labels and a list of 5 labels would be.

Comment: I doubt there exist a single formula, but having data it is possible to establish. You have classes a b c with their known sizes, and you have clusters 1 2 3 4 5 with their known sizes. Consider all variants of correspondence. Let, e.g., a~1, b~2, c~3. Arrange (permute) cluster data so that the agreement is maximal and compute the ARI value. Go to another variant, repeat. You will have a good deal of job to do. I speculate that only in case of equal sized classes and equal sized clusters one could try to come onto a math formula, without actually doing the pairing&arrangement job.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Maybe a permutation approach for clustering labels would be the best here, running it enough times to have an estimation of maximum expected ARI values.